# Error when installing curl debian squeeze

Tags: php, curl, debian

I have set up an [ISPconfig](http://www.ispconfig.org/) server and am now trying to install curl.  I'm using apt-get to install php5-curl and it seems to be throwing up an error.

After I press "y" to accept the install it takes me to a screen that says

```
php5 (5.3.3-7+squeeze5) squeeze-security; urgency=high

  * The following new directives were added as part of security fixes:
    - max_input_vars - specifies how many GET/POST/COOKIE input variables
      may be accepted.  Default value is set to 1000.
    - xsl.security_prefs - define forbidden operations within XSLT
      stylesheets.  Write operations are now disabled by default.

 -- Ondřej Surý <ondrej@debian.org>  Mon, 23 Jan 2012 12:22:26 +0100

php5 (5.3.3-7+squeeze4) squeeze-security; urgency=low

  * Updated blowfish crypt() algorithm fixes the 8-bit character handling
    vulnerability (CVE-2011-2483) and adds more self-tests.  Unfortunately
    this change is incompatible with some old (wrong) generated hashes for
    passwords containing 8-bit characters.  Therefore the new salt prefix
    '$2x$' was introduced which can be used as a replacement for '$2a$'
    salt prefix in the password database in case the incompatibility is
    found.

 -- Ondřej Surý <ondrej@debian.org>  Mon, 04 Jul 2011 10:31:16 +0200

/tmp/tmp93fjeS
```

Please help me with what I should do.

Comment: should ask in serverfault.com

Comment: I don't see any error message in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to give an update on this issue.  I posted the issue on serverfault as well and got the response to remove apt-listchanges and then try again.  Doing this worked.

```
apt-get remove apt-listchanges
```

Then

```
apt-get install php5-curl
```

This worked like a charm for me.

https://serverfault.com/questions/359619/error-when-installing-curl-debian-squeeze

Answer (score 0):

Try to force it.

```
apt-get install php5-curl -f
```

Comment: That produces the same thing.  Not sure what is going on.